# ¿Qué significa "salir del paso?"

Tags: modismos

Estoy leyendo [esta página](http://www.genbeta.com/mensajeria-instantanea/como-puedo-chatear-con-traduccion-simultanea-genbeta-responde), y tiene la frase:

> Es una solución para **salir del paso**. Da mejores resultados entre idiomas de origen indoeuropeo, como es de esperar. Pero si se necesita una traducción más fiable, o nos buscamos la ayuda de un traductor profesional o acudimos a opciones automáticas de pago.

Supongo que "salir del paso" es una frase idiomática, ¿no?  ¿Pero qué significa exactamente? ¿Hay una frase de inglés que signifique lo mismo?

Answer (score 7):

To find a **temporary solution** for a problem.

Answer (score 6):

*workaround* sería una traducción casi literal de *una solución para salir del paso*.

Aunque *workaround* puede no ser apropiado para todos los contextos, para el texto que citas me parece perfecto.

Comment: No exactamente. *Workaround" es más en el sentido de esquivar. Por ejemplo, puedes usar un "workaround" para salir del paso.

Comment: Si, justo eso es lo que decía yo ¿no? No pillo el matiz.

Comment: Perdón, tienes razón, lo había leído mal. En ese caso, en mi opinión tu respuesta no responde correctamente a la pregunta, e incluso puede despistar.

Answer (score 6):

No he encontrado en inglés un modismo equivalente  a “salir del paso”.

Algunos intentos de traducción como *to pull through* o *to get out of trouble* no parecen acertados, ya que significan más bien “salir de un apuro”, pero cuando hacemos algo para salir del paso, no necesariamente estamos en un apuro. A veces optamos por una solución para salir del paso simplemente porque el asunto nos interesa poco. A menudo hacer algo para salir del paso significa hacerlo solo para “cubrir el expediente” (*to keep up appearances*).

Lo más parecido que he encontrado a “salir del paso” son expresiones con *quick fix*, pero *quick fix* tiene una connotación (positiva) de rapidez, mientras que salir del paso transmite una idea principal (negativa) de solución falsa, imperfecta o provisional.

Otras expresiones relacionadas, pero creo que no sinónimas: *to do the bare minimum*, *to do enough to get by*.

Answer (score 5):

Definiciónes del [thefreedictionary](http://es.thefreedictionary.com/paso) :

(1) *salir del paso* Hacer algo solamente para cumplir con una necesidad o una obligación, pero sin poner interés, cuidado o atención.

(2) *salir del paso*
hacer algo para sólo para cumplir una necesidad o una obligación
Es un buen pretexto para salir del paso y poder continuar con nuestro proyecto.

En inglés: As a first step / In the first instance?

Comment: "As a first step" se dice "como un primer paso/aproximación". Cuando haces algo "para salir del paso" lo haces por necesidad, necesitas una solución pero no encuentras la adecuada. Entonces, usas una solución hecha sin poner mucho interés y que puede ser temporal hasta que se encuentre la solución adecuada.

Comment: En la página estaba leyendo Flimzy, se preguntaba por un chat con traducción simultánea. La solución para "salir del paso" es usar los bots de Google Translator. Es "para salir del paso" porque las traducciones que hace no son correctas muchas veces, pero más o menos hace lo que se quiere. Cuando haya un traductor que traduzca todo correctamente, se reemplazará. O puede ser que Google Translator mismamente mejor mucho, pero ahora mismo no es así.

Comment: Fox Lingo sugiere  "muddle through"

Comment: Even though I don't completely agree with the recommended English translation to the phrase, I think these definitions would be the most accurate.

Answer (score 2):

[Según RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=paso) significa:

> **paso1.**
>
> (Del lat. passus).
>
> [...]
>
> salir alguien del ~.
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Desembarazarse de cualquier manera de un asunto, compromiso, dificultad, apuro o trabajo.

Generalmente, se utiliza para indicar una situación o una solución *temporal* a un problema.

Algunos ejemplos:

> Soy ingeniero, pero estoy en paro y estoy trabajando de camarero para salir del paso.
>
> La tubería goteaba, así que le he puesto un poco de cinta, para salir del paso hasta que venga el fontanero.

En cuanto a la traducción al inglés, la única que se me ocurre es `get by`.

Answer (score 1):

La expresión viene en realidad de un modismo castellano utilizado muy frecuentemente durante la edad media alta y corresponde a las gestas de caballería. Particularmente este modismo fue utilizado en las diferentes guerras de la españa moderna.

Es un recurso muy utilizado, por ejemplo, por Cervantes para ridiculizar las novelas de caballería. Don Quijote suele confundir constantemente un episodio con un paso.

La expresión "Estar en un paso" significó en su momento estar en un aprieto. Cuando alguien quería obtener una disputa con otra persona, le cerraba el camino, "el paso", en clara muestra de combate. Cuando un caballero se pone al paso, es un desafío, como un duelo.

"Salir del paso" era entonces la expresión que se utilizaba para demostrar cobardía o negación del duelo que se le imponía a esa persona, por lo cual el perdedor debía rendirse ante quien lo ponía en tal situación aceptando las condiciones dadas. En general era el héroe quien "cerraba el paso".

Luego esta expresión fue utilizada a "salir de un problema sin solución", ya que un paso es un duelo que no se puede negar, una vez puesto en esa situación, ya no se podía más que aceptar o rendirse, incluso con la muerte.

La mejor traducción en mi opinión es "workaround", ya que es una expresión que significa justamente "para este problema no hay solución específica, **más que darle una vuelta**"

Answer (score 1):

Como han mencionado antes, la RAE establece *salir del paso* como:

> Desembarazarse de cualquier manera de un asunto, compromiso,
>   dificultad, apuro o trabajo

Por lo tanto, la traducción al inglés dependerá de aquello que se trata de esquivar, librar, evitar. Te sugiero usar las siguientes frases acorde a la situación:

**librarte de algo de cualquier manera:**

> get something out of the way (get rid of something)

**Superar o conseguir terminar una situación dificil:**

> get out of a tight spot (difficulty)

**Superar o conseguir terminar un problema(sin especificar la dificultad):**

> get out of trouble (problem)

La frase que me parece mas acertada acorde con la definición de la RAE es simplemente

*get it out of the way*

Answer (score 1):

A good translation of this phrase will depend enormously on the context.  There are lots of good translations on this page that will work in particular contexts, such as *get by, muddle through.* Here are two that I haven't seen mentioned here:

> Get out of it / get out of one's difficulty / get through / get through life

Example:

> La empresa intentó salir del paso con una promesa de indemnizar a los afectados: The company tried to **get through it** with a commitment to compensate those affected.

Also:

> Find a way out

Example:

> (same sentence as before): The company tried to **find a way out** by promising to compensate those affected.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor traducción es to "muddle through".
**Muddle through**, to achieve a certain degree of success but without much skill, polish, experience, or direction: None of us knew much about staging a variety show, so we just had to muddle through.

Answer (score -1):

Salir del paso es correrse del medio y dejar que circulen otras personas como por ejemplo cuando dicen: "salí del paso chica", que quiere decir que se corra del lugar.

Comment: Ese es el significado literal, pero no el siginificado por el que se pregunta.