# ¿Cómo puede traducirse "workaround"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

Estaba leyendo [¿Qué significa “salir del paso?”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2450/1674) y vi como la gente mencionaba la palabra *workaround/work around* en alguna de sus respuestas, pero que otros negaban su equivalencia.

¿Cómo se podría traducir la palabra inglesa *work around*? Me refiero fundamentalmente a la situación en informática en la que se resuelve un tema con un método temporal pero efectivo:

> -¿Qué hiciste con ese bug que tenía el programa, que impedía cargar las variables?
>
> -De momento utilicé como *workaround* un fichero oculto que contiene las variables.

A mí sólo se me ocurre algo así como *solución temporal* o incluso *chapucilla*, si bien esta última tiene una connotación demasiado negativa.

Comment: En Wikipedia te redirigen a [Paliativo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paliativo_(inform%C3%A1tica)). No lo pongo como respuesta porque no me suena muy bien y no creo que alguien realmente lo usaría. Pero en términos de significado está bastante bien.

Comment: *Solución indirecta*, quizás.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Workaround* indica una **solución temporal** que se adopta ante la imposibilidad de aplicar la solución estándar u obvia. Se trata de "salir del paso" hasta que llegue el momento de la solución definitiva. (Al menos esa es la acepción en el sector de la informática)

**Apaño, parche, remiendo** o **chapuza** mantienen el sentido original.

Sin embargo, en mi opinión las siguientes palabras no lo respetan:

- **Paliativo** no tiene el sentido de *solución*, dado que actúa sobre los síntomas.
- **Remedio** pierde el matiz *temporal* ya que puede ser definitivo.

Comment: Lo más polite es "parche". Pero entre nosotros lo podemos llamar llanamente "apañó, chapucilla o ñapa". Al cliente queda mejor venderle walkarounds que chapuzas ¿no? Es lo que yo llamo **hablar Consultor**

Answer (score 6):

Creo que vas en la dirección adecuada.

- Añadiría ***apaño*** a tu lista.
- La respuesta de Rodrigo en los comentarios a tu pregunta, [*paliativo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RYJfZWc), es problemática por sus connotaciones médicas. Ahora bien, la definición de *paliativo* de la RAE nos acaba remitiendo a ***remedio***, que, al contrario de lo que comentan otras respuestas, podríamos considerar otra buena alternativa. Recordemos que *workaround* denota que es una solución indirecta o poco ortodoxa, pero no necesariamente temporal.
- ***Parche*** no funciona en este caso, porque ya es la traducción directa y comúnmente usada de *patch*, y *patch* no es sinónimo de *workaround*.

Comment: También se podría añadir ¨hacer un remiendo¨, aunque su connotación principal sea un arreglo físico para una tela rota o rasgada. Se me ocurre también ¨arreglo/compostura temporal¨.

Answer (score 4):

Si bien las otras respuestas dan opciones para salir del paso (pun intended), IMHO ninguna es traducción *exacta*, y no conozco una. La belleza de *workaround* es que transmite bien la idea de que hemos pasado el problema "por alrededor". Es decir, si bien salimos adelante, *no hemos solucionado* ni un poco el problema original, que sigue existiendo. (Las opciones propuestas me transmiten la idea de que se ha solucionado parcialmente el problema original.) Quizás ***paliativo*** es lo más cercano...

[Hablante de español rioplatense y frecuente usuario de workarounds...]

Comment: Hola Pablo, ¡bienvenido a [spanish.se]! Muy útil respuesta, gracias. Destaco lo de _paliativo_ para que tu sugerencia sea más visible. A seguir contestando :)

Answer (score 3):

Tan solo dar cuenta de que Microsoft, en sus documentos técnicos, utiliza la expresión "**solución alternativa**" para traducir *workaround*.

Por ejemplo, compárese este original inglés:
[KB4569509: Guidance for DNS Server Vulnerability CVE-2020-1350](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/4569509/windows-dns-server-remote-code-execution-vulnerability)
[image: Ejemplo de workaround]

Con su traducción oficial en español:
[KB4569509: Orientación para la vulnerabilidad CVE-2020-1350 del servidor DNS](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/4569509/windows-dns-server-remote-code-execution-vulnerability)

[image: Traducción como "solución alternativa"]

Answer (score 2):

**Solución indirecta**, **imperfecta** o **en la práctica**.

Ejemplo:

> No hay forma de... pero la solución indirecta que yo utilizo en esa situación es...

o bien

> pero la solución que se utiliza en la práctica es...

*aunque esto ciertamente no es una solución perfecta.*

**Y otra idea (¡un poco indirecta!)**:

> Podemos **esquivar** el problema, con etc.

**Otra idea más**:

Inspirado por https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20848/9385, *solución de rodeo*

> -De momento utilicé como **solución de rodeo** un fichero oculto que contiene las variables.