# ¿Es "enguachinar" una corrupción de "enaguachar"?

Tags: etimología, verbos, diferencias-regionales, significado

No sé en otras regiones, pero aquí en Andalucía tenemos una palabreja que usamos, por ejemplo, cuando hemos bebido demasiada agua y notamos el estómago pesado en consecuencia. Así, decimos:

> Tengo el estómago *enguachinao*.

O directamente:

> Estoy *enguachinao*.
>   Me he *enguachinao*.

Es de esas típicas palabras coloquiales que no piensas que vaya a estar en el diccionario. Pero resulta que sí:

> **[enguachinar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FPgfwJy)**
>
> 1. tr. Enaguachar, enaguazar. U. t. c. prnl.

Y de ahí:

> **[enaguachar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Euc4WzG)**
>
> De *en-* y *aguachar*.
>
> 1. tr. Poner demasiada agua en algo.
> 2. tr. Causar en el estómago estorbo y pesadez, como consecuencia de beber mucho o comer mucha fruta. U. t. c. prnl.

Donde encontramos el significado que comentaba al principio. La duda es simple: aunque el diccionario no indica la etimología de *enguachinar*, ¿sería una corrupción de *enaguachar*? A fin de cuentas, esta última lleva en el diccionario desde 1837, mientras que la primera aparece solamente desde 1925.

Bonus: ¿Se usa *enguachinar* fuera de Andalucía?

---

Giro inesperado de guion: hay un caso en el CORDE del siglo XVIII. Negritas mías:

> *Le dije a Blanco, y aún antes de ahora se lo tengo dicho, que me parece preciso se haga en todo aquel valle, desde el principio de la huerta hasta su final una zanja o cauce que recoja todas aquellas aguas que le sobran a la tierra, porque si no, aúnque más se aren, siendo los años de aguas, es preciso **se enguachine** o empantane todo el valle.*
>
> Diego de Vargas y Carvajal, "Carta a Rodríguez Campomanes [Epistolario de Pedro Rodríguez Campomanes]", 1773 (España).

Comment: En la vida lo había oído. Vaya, que en el nordeste de España no se usa :)

Comment: ¿Tendrá algo que ver con el *huachinango* (red snapper)?

Comment: La usaba mi abuelita y mi mamá todavía la usa (70+). Estoy seguro que hoy en día poca gente sabe su significado. Casi seguro decía enguachi**R**nar

Answer (score 2):

No sale la etimología directamente, pero si damos un rodeo...

En Aragón usamos la palabra *aguachinar* o *aguarchinar* con el sentido de poner demasiada agua en algo. He ido a buscarlas al DLE, a ver si tenía suerte, y no he encontrado la segunda, pero sí la primera:

> **[aguachinar](http://dle.rae.es/?w=aguachinar)**
>
> De *[aguachar<sup>2</sup>](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1BimpfK)*.
>
> 1. tr. Estropear un fruto u otro alimento por exceso de agua.
> 2. tr. [Enaguazar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EugJNln).
> 3. tr. Llenar de agua algo.

Y, si sigues ese enlace a *aguachar*, te dice que significa... *enaguachar*.

Por tanto, viendo que todas estas palabras están relacionadas y que *aguachinar* deriva de *aguachar*, no me parece muy retorcido deducir que *enguachinar* se deriva igualmente de *enaguachar*. La primera *a* de *enaguachinar*<sup>*</sup> se ha perdido por el camino porque en una palabra tan larga es muy débil y tiende a desaparecer de la pronunciación.

Comment: ¿Sugieres entonces que la evolución puede haber sido _aguachar_ > _aguachinar_ > _enaguachinar_ (en + aguachinar) > _enguachinar_? He consultado el CORDE y acabo de ver un caso de _enguachinar_ del siglo XVIII, mientras que el más antiguo de _aguachinar_ es del XIX.

Comment: Tal vez *aguachinar* haya derivado de *aguachar* por influencia de *enguachinar*; eso sería coherente con tus hallazgos en el CORDE. Pero ya no me atrevo a deducir más cosas.

Comment: [La RAE dice](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/862240646752604160) que parece una derivación de «enguachar» (que, curiosamente, no existe), al igual que tenemos los pares «aguachar/aguachinar», «chafar/chafarrinar». La evolución sería, según ellos, _enaguachar > enguachar > enguachinar_.